# SD card not recognized by Cubot Note 7

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage

I recently switched to a Cubot Note 7 android phone. This phone has a slot where one may put an additional SD card. As I used a 16 GB Fujifilm micro SDHC card in my old smartphone, I just put that one in. However, this card is not recognized by the Note 7.

- There is no popup or notification notifying me of the new card.
- There is no indication of a recognized sd card under the storage settings. In fact: Nowhere in settings, I find any option concerning an sd card. When searching the settings, the only "card" related option is "load certificate from sd card" (which does not work as the card is not recognized in the first place).
- I tried formatting the card on my PC either with FAT32 or with exFAT. The PC, however, is perfectly fine with the card.

Details:

- Card 16 GB Fujifilm micro SDHC
- Cubot Note 7 with android 10

Comment: As the sd-card obviously works you should test the phone with a different sd-card. If that don't work, too it may be a hardware defect of the phone.